# How to pass email to stripe when using stripe elements?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

By default, when using stripe in popup ([stripe-checkout](https://stripe.com/blog/stripe-checkout)) the Email field is sent as `card[name]`.

But when I'm using stripe elements (stripe fields as inline fields, without popup) there is no email field and if I add my own email field it seems to be ignored by stripe. It results in customer being added on stripe without email which makes it tedious to identify one customer from another.

How can I modify this code to pass email to stripe?
demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ywain/foc0L56q/

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

<body>
  <form action="//httpbin.org/post" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" />
    <div class="group">
      <label>
        <span>Card</span>
        <div id="card-element" class="field"></div>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <label>
        <span>Email</span>
        <input id="email" name="email" class="field" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com" />
      </label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Pay $25</button>
    <div class="outcome">
      <div class="error"></div>
      <div class="success">
        Success! Your Stripe token is <span class="token"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

```
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh');
var elements = stripe.elements();
var card = elements.create('card');
card.mount('#card-element');

function setOutcome(result) {
  var successElement = document.querySelector('.success');
  var errorElement = document.querySelector('.error');
  successElement.classList.remove('visible');
  errorElement.classList.remove('visible');

  if (result.token) {
    // In this example, we're simply displaying the token
    successElement.querySelector('.token').textContent = result.token.id;
    successElement.classList.add('visible');

    // In a real integration, you'd submit the form with the token to your backend server
    var form = document.querySelector('form');
    form.querySelector('input[name="token"]').setAttribute('value', result.token.id);
    form.submit();
  } else if (result.error) {
    errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    errorElement.classList.add('visible');
  }
}

card.on('change', function(event) {
  setOutcome(event);
});

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  stripe.createToken(card).then(setOutcome);
});
```

Comment: Are you sending it with the token as `token.email` or with the `data-email` [optional params](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#optional)? card name is reserved for the cardholder name (the name that's printed on the credit card), and supplying the email there may fail your transactions.

Comment: @Máté I think you're confusing few things. `token` is an object I receive from stripe, not what I send to stripe. `data-email` param seems to be reserved for checkout component (the popup), not for elements. So no, I don't use `data-email`, nor `token.email`, but you can see it all in the code I've attached. Also `card[name]` seems to be something exclusive for the popup and for some weird reason an email is send as `card[name]` there, but that's not related to my issue, as I'm using stripe **elements**, not stripe **checkout/popup**.

Comment: apologies then. I followed that link in the original post, that lead me to a blog post, which at the bottom lead me to the checkout docs. The checkout has the data- params, and I assumed that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this in backend code, not in frontend Javascript. When your backend receives the payment token and email address from the POST data the form sends, you'd use that to set the `email` property when creating a customer. [0] It would be similar to this(in PHP as an example)

```php
  $token  = $_POST['token'];
  $email  = $_POST['email'];

  $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
      'email' => $email,
      'source'  => $token,
  ]);

  $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
      'customer' => $customer->id,
      'amount'   => 5000,
      'currency' => 'usd',
  ]);
```

[0] - https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create#create_customer-email

Comment: Just want to point out now 4 years later that Stripe can and does (almost by default) not pass charges server side like the above.  It all happens client side.

Answer (score 1):

Add a hidden field in you form for email

```
<input name="email" type="hidden" value="<?php echo "your_email";?>"/>
```

Get it in post function in php code